# Generate HTML Table with 2 javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hello I try to generate an HTML Table with two arrays. Where one array is for the Headers and the other one is for the rows. The arrays work like a blast but the generation of the HTML-Table wont work.....

Here is my little Function: (For the arrays and they work like a blast)

```
function loadDepartments() {

    var query = "$select=DepartmentID,WEBName";

    getListItems("example.at", "WEBepartments", query, function (results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            departments.push({
                name: result.WEBName,
                id: result.DepartmentID
            });
        });
        loadCountries();
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function loadCountries() {

    var query = "$select=CountryID,WEBName,Acronym";

    getListItems("https://intranet.windkraft.at/", "WEBCountries", query, function (results) {
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            countries.push({
                name: result.WEBName,
                id: result.CountryID,
                acronym: result.Acronym
            });
        });
        doNextSteps();
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

And here my latest Try:

```
function doNextSteps() {

    //Create a HTML Table element.
    var table = document.createElement("TABLE");
    table.border = "1";

    //Get the count of columns and rows.
    var columnCount = departments.length;
    var rowCount = countries.length;


    //Add the header row.
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
        var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
        headerCell.innerHTML = columnCount[0];
        row.appendChild(headerCell);
    }

    //Add the data rows.
    for (var i = 1; i < countries.length; i++) {
        row = table.insertRow(-1);
        for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
            var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
            cell.innerHTML = rowCount[0];
        }
    }

    var dvTable = document.getElementById("dvTable");
    dvTable.innerHTML = "";
    dvTable.appendChild(table);

}
```

But wont work the only thing i get is nothing or undefined. And i have no clue why becouse its the first time i try to generate a HTML Table with javascript. So any help would be great.

Thx for your Time and Help.

Comment: your `columnCount` variable is set to the array's length. You then try and access it like an array `headerCell.innerHTML = columnCount[0];`. You may want to replace `columnCount[0]` with `departments[i]`. Since I doubt you want to output the number of rows/columns into the fields

Comment: @Beep now it generates it  but only with [object object].... But thanks.

Comment: Yes, your countries and departments arrays contain objects. Select their property, e.g `departments[i].name`

Comment: @Beep Well what should i say just thanks now it works. Hope i get soon better in the Programming world.....